# AC_SEARCH_LIBS is not finding my library

Tags: c, autotools, glib

I'm currently learning autotools and have been trying to work out how to use AC_SEARCH_LIBS so I have picked a [function](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.26/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-ascii-digit-value) at random from the glib manual to include in my c project:

> gint g_ascii_digit_value (gchar c);

Next I added a `AC_SEARCH_LIBS` macro to my `configure.ac`:

```
AC_INIT([myproject], [123], [me@example.com])
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([g_ascii_digit_value], [glib], [], [
  AC_MSG_ERROR([unable to find the g_ascii_digit_value() function])
])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
AC_PROG_CC
AC_OUTPUT([Makefile src/Makefile])
```

However, when I run `autoreconf -i` followed by `./configure`, I get the error:

```
configure: error: unable to find the g_ascii_digit_value() function
```

I am using OS X and have checked that I have the glib library installed:

```
snowch:autoconf snowch$ brew install glib
Warning: glib-2.42.1 already installed
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of searching, I found that I needed to use `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` as shown below:

```
AC_INIT([myproject], [123], [me@example.com])

PKG_CHECK_MODULES([GLIB], [glib-2.0 >= 2.3.0])
AC_SUBST([GLIB_CFLAGS])
AC_SUBST([GLIB_LIBS])

AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
AC_PROG_CC
AC_OUTPUT([Makefile src/Makefile])
```

Then the `GLIB` variables needed to be added to `src/Makefile.am`:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = helloworld

helloworld_SOURCES = main.c
helloworld_LDADD = @GLIB_LIBS@
helloworld_CFLAGS = @GLIB_CFLAGS@
```

Comment: you can also use `$(GLIB_CFLAGS)` and `$(GLIB_LIBS)` instead of the `@` notation to replace the values.